# Method with no parameters in c# and still a method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

All i am trying to do is to check whether all elements of list B are in list A

```
        if (listA.All(element => listB.Contains(element))
        {
            return;
        }
```

Someone came up with another solution saying this would work and it worked!

```
       if (listA.All(listB.Contains))
            return;
```

Now, (I know it works),

1. Why did the compiler doesn't require a () near contains in the second method?
2. If in future, say, I want this to compare case-insensitive, how would I do it with second method ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method asks for a predicate as a parameter: `Func<T, bool>` where `T` is the same type is the items in the `List<T>`.   This code works because it provides just such a method.  The [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method will return a value indicating whether the result of calling the provided predicate on each item in the list results in `true`.  The parameter is a *reference* to the `Contains` method which matches the required `Func<T, bool>`, taking a single parameter `T` and returning a `bool`.

Consider these two lines of code:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate1 = s => s.Length > 5;
Func<string, bool> predicate2 = listB.Contains;
```

Both of these lines work because the expressions to the right of the assignment operators evaluate to methods that take a single `string` parameter, and return a `bool`.  You could pass `predicate1` or `predicate2` into the [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method.  It's the same as the code you provided, except that the predicate is passed directly, instead of being stored in a variable first and the variable passed in.

The `Contains` method is not actually called as the parameter though.  It is only called internally by the [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method.

If you wanted to do a case-insensitive search, *and* use the same sort of syntax as above, you would need a method that performed a case-insensitive search.  You could always just use a custom anonymous method though:

```
listA.All(x => listB.Any(
    z => string.Equals(x, z, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Specifically, a predicate of type `Func<T, bool>`

Comment: Thanks Dan. If in future, say, I want this to compare case-insensitive, how would I do it with second method ?

Comment: @Dan: Thanks for the edit Dan.. but, still by the words "This code works because it provides just such a method" means what ? Also, could you interpret "listB.Contains" for me?

Comment: @Dan: Kind of.. But, i can understand that "Func<T,bool>" is the parameter that has to be supplied to "All" method. But is listB.Contains is expanded to "Func<ListB, Bool>"?